# Exercises in *yiras shamaim* (awe of the Lord)

Tags: mussar-ethics, avodath-hashem, yirat-shamaim

I have, it seems, no problem relating to Hashem with *ahava* - one of my main motivations in *avoda* is to try to make him *benachas* (happy), like I would my parents.

Relating to *yirah* is another story. I am looking a set of exercises to try to build up *yiras shamaim*. Any thoughts what could help? or references?

Thank you very much.

Comment: See the Bilvavi Mishkan Evneh, which is online in English for free: http://bilvavi.net/english_trans (part 1, section 5 for example); see also here http://www.azamra.org/Advice/awe.html (Likutei Eitzot)

Comment: see also this by Rabbi Yaakov Ades http://dafyomireview.com/438 especially gate 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the more you know/understand the greatness of God the more you will have awe/fear of Him. This is why Moshe Rabeinu was the humblest of all men despite that he achieved more than any other person in history ([source](http://dafyomireview.com/audio/cord1.mp3)). He knew God more than anyone else, hence his fear/awe of God made Him totally humble. therefore for any exercises you do, the effectiveness will depend on the extent of your knowledge of God and clarity of faith.

Some books which teach on knowing God - chovos halevavos shaar yichud with commentaries, Kuzari with commentaries, sefer haikarim, although there are various false beliefs floating around that their premises have been refuted. (so ask your Rav if its suitable for you)

The Chafetz Chaim also recommends (in sefer mitzvot #3) reading books which reveal the Creator's glory as a way to build love and fear/awe of God.

As for exercises, there are some interesting ones in the book Jewish Meditation by Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan, though i dont know how recommended that book is for mainstream.

Disclaimer: all this assumes you are growing in your talmud learning as Rabbi Nissan Kaplan says "it is impossible to reach any level unless you are first growing in learning. Otherwise, it has no tefisa (permanence)" [source audio here](http://ravkaplan.dafyomireview.com/cdd/mussar/5769-Mussar/13-maalos_hatorah.mp3)

Comment: thank you. the rav Kaplan reference is interesting. I was looking for practical exercises mostly, but reference list will do. Thank you very much.

Comment: see this http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=398 and look for "practical exercise of yichuda-ila'ah" though i cant say how reliable its approach is

Comment: thank you, this was very valuable. will try it. i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to think, understand and internalize that G-d Almighty is literally Almighty (you can think of the spesific mighty things that he did) (then it is almost impossible not to fear him)

Comment: http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/851272/rabbi-mayer-e-twersky/yiras-shamayim-the-foundation-of-life/